# Room-runtime: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.:

Tags: android, database, android-studio, kotlin, android-room

Hello I get an error after adding Room dependencies and changing the Kotlin version doesn't seem to fix the issue.

error:

```
/Users/Erin/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c3d04919ade1d841f45db1aa77dde355/transformed/room-runtime-2.4.3-api.jar!/META-INF/room-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
```

build.gradle(:app)

```
dependencies{
    def room_version = "2.4.3"

        //room dependencies
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
// To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version")

}
```

build.gradle(:project)

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.42")
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Kotlin version to 1.6.10

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
```

Comment: I get this error updating it to 1.6.10. 

e: This version (1.1.0-beta01) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.31 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.10 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using an older version of the room.. but it seems to be a temporary fix.

Comment: you also need update your compose version. I think compose 1.2.x aaccept all version of kotlin.